# This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, app-service-environment

I am working on Azure App service API apps.

I followed the steps available in the below link, for implementing user authentication concept to the ToDoListAngular project and successfully deployed in azure, but when i test with the ToDoListAngluar project azure url to add the todoitem it shows error on Google Chrome Address bar "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources".
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-user-principal-auth/#overview

Please tell me how to resolve the above error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of your API Urls does not have `https://` at the beginning.

My best bet is the "toDoListAPIURL" in your front end site's application settings on the portal. There are a ton of API urls in the source code to check if that doesn't do it. Going back through the [getting started tutorial](//azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started/) should have them all.